# Reaching specific data on Excel without opening it by using ADO

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I am trying to extract some data from another excel workbook. I am doing with vba codes given below by opening and closing excel workbooks one by one. But that process takes too much time, so I am trying to learn a way to get same data without opening excel workbooks. Can I do that by using ADO connection?

```
Sub GetOldNumber()

Dim adres As String
Dim m As String
Dim found As Range
Dim count As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Worksheets("Sayfa1")


For i = 1 To 10
    With sht

    adres = "C:\users\ali\Desktop" & "\" & .Cells(i, 10) & "\" _
    & .Cells(i, 11) & ".xlsx"

    Workbooks.Open (adres)
    m = .Cells(i, 4).Value

    End With



count = 0

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

    Set found = ws.Cells.Find(What:=m, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not found Is Nothing Then
            sht.Cells(i, 12) = found.Cells.Offset(-1, 0)
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next ws
If count = 0 Then MsgBox "No Matches Found"

ActiveWorkbook.Close
Next



End Sub
```

Comment: You need to open a workbook to get at the data inside. ADO will also do the same. But first things first: you're not doing anything with the opened workbook in code you posted.

Comment: @MikeC - This is (one reason) `ActiveWorkbook` is evil.  The OPs code relies on the `Workbooks.Open` call changing it.

Comment: @MikeC - I know using ActiveWorkbook is kind of dangerous but here it is ok. I search in opened workbook and when I find, I do,
'sht.Cells(i, 12) = found.Cells.Offset(-1, 0)'

Comment: @Comintern ActiveWorkbook is fine here. But I have to admit it is a little bit scary :)

Comment: @ali - It may work, but it is completely unnecessary - Workbooks.Open returns a reference to the opened document.  This code can be broken by the user clicking on an Excel icon on the Taskbar while it's running.

Comment: @Comintern - How can I get rid of that here? also I have added screenupdating false line on top. It may also prevent user to click anywhere, I suppose :)

Comment: Are you opening the same wb again and again?

Comment: @MikeC - no, address(adres in Turkish) is changing at every iteration.

Comment: So, at this point , what are we trying to solve?

Comment: @MikeC doing the same things with a faster way, ADO maybe.

Comment: If you're opening 10 workbooks, how long is it taking now?

Comment: @ali - To answer your question about how to pull out the `ActiveWorkbook` calls: `Dim wb As Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open adres`, and finally `For Each ws In wb.Worksheets` and `wb.Close`. Note that using ADO will sidestep this (since you obviously don't need to open the Workbook at all...).

Comment: @MikeC - It is actually much more than 10. It ll be around 100 workbooks :) It is not taking too much time with 10 workbooks right now. But 100 workbooks take approximately 5 mins.

Comment: @Comintern - Thanks I have done it. What did you mean by "sidestep"? You mean it is gonna make process longer or it will be a short way to do this?

Comment: The workbook needs to be opened; it is just that ADO might do it for you. Five minutes for 100 workbooks is not unreasonable, considering you're also processing the data of 100 workbooks in those five minutes.

Comment: @MikeC - So ADO can't make it in like seconds? Ok. I just wondered if I could do it faster.

Comment: If 5 minutes is too much for you, you can try ADO. No harm. It could be a learning experience. Who knows, it might be faster.

Comment: @MikeC - Nice. :) So question is how. I used ADO over an excel file to send an SQL query. But here, what I want to do here is a bit different. There are more than one sheet. Sheet data is not like data table.